# Iframe youtube player inside google chrome extension with manifest V3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, cross-site, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to use a youtube player inside my chrome extension's popup page.
By default I'm getting an error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'. 
Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

So I added to `manifeset.json`

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts;"
},
"sandbox": {
  "pages": [
    "/videoPlayer.html"
  ]
},
```

And moved player logic to this sandbox page, but still have the same erorr

```
Refused to load the script 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api' 
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". 
Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

As I understand according to make it works I need to add `allow-same-origin` which is considered as unsecure.

```
"content_security_policy": {
    "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts allow-same-origin;"
},
```

And as far as I understand nested iframes cannot have less sandbox restrictions than their most restrictive ancestor iframe.

Does anybody know how I can bypass restrictions of chrome-extension's manifest rules and use youtube video player in my chrome extension?

Comment: Not possible in ManifestV3 until https://crbug.com/1220994 is fixed.

Comment: Do you know how much time usually takes the chromium team to fix such issues?

Comment: Several years. The team is too small.